# How to do I pass data to a class object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, fetch, es6-promise, es6-class

I have a weather app that I'm building to learn ES6 classes and API calls using Fetch. I'm currently passing the returned data from the fetch call at `weather.getWeather(pos)`, to specific methods within a class called `UI`. The purpose of the class is to maniuplate the returned data in the DOM.

Can I pass the `data` variable to the UI class constructor so that I can reference it within my UI class methods?

Or is it best practice to only pass in data to the methods that use/need it?

```
//init weather and ui objects
const weather = new Weather();
const ui = new UI();

const form = document.getElementById("weather-form");
const loco = document.getElementById("location");

loco.addEventListener("click", () => {
    output.innerHTML = '';
    // Validation
    weather.validation(success, weather.error);
    
    function success(pos) {
        weather.getWeather(pos)
            .then(data => {
                ui.currentWeather(data);
                ui.forecast(data);
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
    }
});


//2. Weather API Call

    async getWeather(pos) {
        const crd = pos.coords;

        let lat = crd.latitude;
        let long = crd.longitude;

        //Current weather
        let current = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&appid=${this.key}&units=metric`);

        //Forecast
        let fiveDay = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&exclude=${this.exclude}&appid=${this.key}&units=metric`)
        

        let now = await current.json();
        let forecast = await fiveDay.json();

        return {
            now,
            forecast
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since it's 2020 an you're using ES6, why not use `async` functions and `await` as well? This helps minimize how much code you have to write.

Comment: Sorry, my question is not very clear. I've updated to show the async API call.

Comment: You'd generally only pass arguments to functions that want them, like you wouldn't just call a function with some stuff for no reason. What does `currentWeather` and `forecast` want? Do they take an object and just look for specific keys? Do they need multiple arguments?

Comment: @tadman they just take the `data` object with `now` and `forecast` objects that are returned from the promise. I then passed the `data` object into the `currentWeather` and `forecast` methods. This was the only way I could figure out getting that information to those methods. I'm just wondering if its easier to pass the data object to the UI class constructor and then reference the data object as `this.data = data`. I have a few variables that use the data object that I think would clean up the code if they were in the constructor. I'm not sure.

Comment: If multiple methods within your UI class are relying on `data`, you could use a setter such as `.setData()`, which would then set the data attribute in your class (rather than passing it through into the constructor)

Comment: Since we have absolutely no idea what arguments those functions are expecting, if any, it's hard to say if this will work at all.